# I want to have Google Assistant installed on Ubuntu listening when screen/user lock is on

Tags: ubuntu, lockscreen, google-assistant-sdk

I followed instructions from the below URL:
https://www.freeyourdesktop.com/2018/09/install-google-assistant-in-gnome-shell/
I would like to have the Google Assistant listening for "ok google" when the lock screen is on. I have it setup so that the WiFi remains on when the tablet is in a low power state. Otherwise, I need to disable the lock screen.

Comment: I don't think that Ubuntu will allow a process to operate and take user input while locked. That seems like a potential security vulnerability.

Comment: Your probably correct.